# Angular assing attribute to all child elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I have a custom component in angular that i re-use everywere in my app. This is a button component and i call it like this where i want to use it: `<app-delete-btn></app-delete-btn>`

I want to set the attribute `tabindex="1"` to my component but it does not work.
This attribute gives a <kbd>TAB</kbd> order to specific html elements.

Upon inspecting this strange behaviour, and as of my understanding, `tabindex` works but you have to specify it for the parent and **ALL** the child components

So i did this and it worked:

- Upon declaring my custom component in my html `<app-delete-btn tabindex="1"></app-delete-btn>` i gave him the `tabindex`
- and then i had to add it in the `app-delete-btn.ts` button inside the component `<button tabindex="1">Delete</button>`

The problem is that i may re-use that button therefore i can't add the tabindex from within the component itself otherwise is going to apply everywhere i use it.

Finally my question is:
Is there a way when calling `<app-delete-btn></app-delete-btn>` to assing a `tabindex` property to all of it's childrens (and by childrens i mean the button delcared in the html of the component)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your button :

```js
@HostBinding('attr.tab-index')
tabIndex = 1;
```

This should do the exact same thing as this

```js
<app-delete-btn tabindex="1"></app-delete-btn>
```

But automatically

Comment: Where should i add it ? In the ts component or in the HTML?